# App Privacy: Why does the railroad company need my steps made and other health data? How-To revoke?

Tags: iphone, applications, privacy, health.app

[image]

I was surprised to see that the local railroad company, accesses **Health and Fitness** data. I use this app only as a timetable for trains.

> The [Health app](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/collect-health-and-fitness-information-iphbb8259c61/ios) can track your daily footsteps and the flights of
> stairs you climb. You can manually add other information like body
> weight and caffeine intake, and track additional data with other apps
> (such as nutrition and fitness apps) and devices that are compatible
> with Health (such as Apple Watch, AirPods, weight scales, and blood
> pressure monitors, all sold separately).

Is there a plausible reason why the railroad company wants to collect my health data? How can I prohibit this (expect uninstalling the app and use web site)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is required for the EasyRide functionality. The first time you activate it within the app you are asked to grant access by iOS.

[image]

<sup>(EasyRide wants to access your Fitness data to optimally support you, e.g. if you forget to sign-off after a trip)</sup>

If you decline you can't use the EasyRide functionality

[image]

You can check in System Preferences -> Health whether the SBB app has access to its data or not. Access can also be revoked from there.